# Reescalar imagen en android

Tags: android, android-studio, jsoup, image-view

*Buenas, tengo una duda con respecto al tema de cargar una imagen desde `JSOUP` a un `ImageView` en `Android Studio.` La cosa es que consigo cargar la imagen, pero se ve muy chiquita y me gustaría que ocupe todo el ancho de la pantalla.

Adjunto imagen descriptiva:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el layout donde se encuentra el imageView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/CardView.Light"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivPaginas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Este es el layout de la actividad:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.TMO.TMOLector">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_below="@+id/arriba"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

El adaptador:

```
public class TMOLectorAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TMOLectorAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<TMOLectorClase> tmoLectorClases;
    private Context context;

    public TMOLectorAdapter(ArrayList<TMOLectorClase> tmoItems, Context context) {
        this.tmoLectorClases = tmoItems;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TMOLectorAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adaptador_lectortmo, parent, false);
        return new TMOLectorAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TMOLectorAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        TMOLectorClase tmoLectorClase = this.tmoLectorClases.get(position);
        Picasso.get().load(tmoLectorClase.getImg()).into(holder.iv);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return tmoLectorClases.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        ImageView iv;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View view) {
            super(view);
            iv = view.findViewById(R.id.ivPaginas);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(tmoItems.get(itemPosition).getUrlCapitulo())));
        }
    }

    public void setFilter(ArrayList<TMOLectorClase> newList) {
        tmoLectorClases = new ArrayList<>();
        tmoLectorClases.addAll(newList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void updateData(ArrayList<TMOLectorClase> items) {
        this.tmoLectorClases = items;
    }
}
```

Ya probé usando `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` pero no me sive ya que me corta las imágenes

Comment: ¿Has probado con el tipo FitXY en scaleType? Con eso ocupará todo el espacio en la ancho sin embargo, por la forma que cargas la imagen me parece que se distorcionará. Prueba y me cuentas cómo va.

Comment: Buenas, últimamenteme llegan tardes las notificaciones. Sí, ya he probado pero no funcionó

Comment: Quieres que cubra todo lo ancho y alto? si es así necesitarías deslizar hacia abajo para ver toda la imagen, eso es lo que deseas realizar?

Comment: Tal cual, eso mismo @Elenasys

Comment: Reescalar se puede pero dentro de un contenedor siempre se vera chico pora sus dimensiones, lo que tienes que hacer es hacer un scrollview, con una imagen con el aspecto ratio de la imagen  que el image view tal altura a su ancho como la imagen. el usuario tendria que escrolear para ir viendo. Implementa un recyclerview si son varias imagenes con esa dimenssion y que el ususario scrollee, si tienes idea implementas zoom yo lo hago con la image matrix del imageview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido solucionar temporalmente mi problema de la siguiente manera. Lo primero fue crear un `LinearLayout` en mi **adaptador** con atributos `match_parent` y adentro le asigné el `ImageView` con los atributos en `wrap_content`:

```
LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blanco">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/ivPaginas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Luego, al `layout` de mi `activity` le cambié los atributos del `RelativeLayout` incluyendo `gravity` y `layout_gravity`, tanto al `LinearLayout` como al `RecyclerView` le cambié los atributos del ancho por `wrap_content`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.Todas.TMO.TMOLector"
    android:background="@color/blanco"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```